# {"error":"invalid_client"} from Spotify Web Api when trying to refresh token

Tags: c++, qt, spotify

I'm a newbie in terms both on Qt and C++ but i was trying to play a bit with a spotify web api for uni project. Unfortunately I got stuck on posting my refresh token to api to get new access token. Every time i do that, i'm getting response {"error":"invalid_client"}. I've made sure both my client id and client secret are correct. I think there is an mistake somewhere in my header but i've tried few things and it didn't do much.

Here's my code:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked(){

    QNetworkAccessManager * manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);

    QUrl url("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QString header = "my_client_id:my_client_secret";
    QByteArray ba;
    ba.append(header);
    ui->teOutput->appendPlainText(ba.toBase64());
    QString full_header= "Authorization: Basic " + ba.toBase64();
    //ui->teOutput->appendPlainText(full_header);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, full_header);

    QUrlQuery params;
    params.addQueryItem("grant_type", "refresh_token");
    params.addQueryItem("refresh_token", "here_is_my_refresh_token");

    connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(onFinish(QNetworkReply *)));
    manager->post(request, params.query().toUtf8());
    //ui->teOutput->appendPlainText(params.query().toUtf8());
}

void MainWindow::onFinish(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    QString data = rep->readAll();
    ui->teOutput->appendPlainText(data);
}
```

And here's how my request should look like (as suggested i've checked that using cUrl)

```
curl -X "POST" -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxx" -d grant_type=refresh_token -d refresh_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token
```

Comment: Try cURL, if you'll succeed, please, update your question with your request details (hiding sensitive information).

Comment: What type of Authorization Flows are you following? https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

Comment: @eyllanesc Authorization Code Flow

Comment: @x00 I've used curl on cmd and it worked. 
Here's my request:
curl -X "POST" -H "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxx" -d grant_type=refresh_token -d refresh_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `-H "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxx"` is equivalent to:

```cpp
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxx");
```

So you should use instead of `request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, full_header);`.

---

Although it is not necessary to implement all the logic since the Spotify API uses OAuth2 that Qt implements in the [Qt Network Authorization](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetworkauth-index.html) module.

Only the QNetworkRequest header should be modified when requesting or refreshing the token since that is not part of the Oauth2 standard.

**constants.h**

```cpp
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

#include <QByteArray>
#include <QUrl>

namespace Constants {
    const QByteArray SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxx";
    const QByteArray SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET = "yyyyyyyy";

    const QUrl SPOTIFY_AUTHORIZATION_URL = QUrl("https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize");
    const QUrl SPOTIFY_ACCESSTOKEN_URL = QUrl("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");
}

#endif // CONSTANTS_H
```

**networkaccessmanager.h**

```cpp
#ifndef NETWORKACCESSMANAGER_H
#define NETWORKACCESSMANAGER_H

#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class NetworkAccessManager : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
public:
    using QNetworkAccessManager::QNetworkAccessManager;
protected:
    QNetworkReply *createRequest(Operation op, const QNetworkRequest &request, QIODevice *outgoingData);
};

#endif // NETWORKACCESSMANAGER_H
```

**networkaccessmanager.cpp**

```cpp
#include "networkaccessmanager.h"
#include "constants.h"
#include <QtGlobal>

QNetworkReply *NetworkAccessManager::createRequest(QNetworkAccessManager::Operation op,
                                                   const QNetworkRequest &request,
                                                   QIODevice *outgoingData)
{
    QNetworkRequest r(request);
    if(r.url() == Constants::SPOTIFY_ACCESSTOKEN_URL)
        r.setRawHeader("Authorization",
                       "Basic " +
                       QByteArray(Constants::SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID + ":" + Constants::SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET).toBase64());
    return QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(op, r, outgoingData);
}
```

**spotifywrapper.h**

```cpp
#ifndef SPOTIFYWRAPPER_H
#define SPOTIFYWRAPPER_H

#include <QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow>
#include <QObject>

class SpotifyWrapper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SpotifyWrapper(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QNetworkReply *me();
public Q_SLOTS:
    void grant();
Q_SIGNALS:
    void authenticated();
private:
    QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow oauth2;
};

#endif // SPOTIFYWRAPPER_H
```

**spotifywrapper.cpp**

```cpp
#include "spotifywrapper.h"
#include "networkaccessmanager.h"
#include "constants.h"

#include <QDesktopServices>
#include <QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler>
#include <QUrlQuery>

SpotifyWrapper::SpotifyWrapper(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler * replyHandler = new QOAuthHttpServerReplyHandler(1337, this);
    replyHandler->setCallbackPath("callback");
    oauth2.setNetworkAccessManager(new NetworkAccessManager(this));
    oauth2.setReplyHandler(replyHandler);
    oauth2.setAuthorizationUrl(Constants::SPOTIFY_AUTHORIZATION_URL);
    oauth2.setAccessTokenUrl(Constants::SPOTIFY_ACCESSTOKEN_URL);
    oauth2.setClientIdentifier(Constants::SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID);
    oauth2.setScope("user-read-private user-read-email");
    oauth2.setState("34fFs29kd09");
    connect(&oauth2, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::authorizeWithBrowser,
            &QDesktopServices::openUrl);
    connect(&oauth2, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::statusChanged, [=](
            QAbstractOAuth::Status status) {
        if (status == QAbstractOAuth::Status::Granted){
            emit authenticated();
        }
    });
}

void SpotifyWrapper::grant()
{
    oauth2.grant();
}

QNetworkReply *SpotifyWrapper::me()
{
    return oauth2.get(QUrl("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me"));
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "spotifywrapper.h"

#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);
    SpotifyWrapper wrapper;
    wrapper.grant();
    QObject::connect(&wrapper, &SpotifyWrapper::authenticated, [&wrapper](){
        qDebug() << "authenticated";
        QNetworkReply *reply = wrapper.me();
        QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=]() {
                reply->deleteLater();
                if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
                    qDebug() << reply->errorString();
                    return;
                }
                qDebug() << reply->readAll();
                QTimer::singleShot(1000, &QCoreApplication::quit);
        });
    });
    return a.exec();
}
```

You must also set as Redirect URIs in the SETTINGS of your application to "http://127.0.0.1:1337/callback":

[image]

<sub>The full example can be found [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/59708421)</sub>